# SQL/server connection and security

Tags: sql, database, security, connection

I'm starting a project (actually, two to be precise) and using an SQL database. I am new the SQL, but am curious about one decision I am trying to make right now.

One project is an internal tracking system for stuff we make, another is a little game I'm making. I'm expecting about 1 to 10 concurrent connections on the first, and no idea but can dream for triple to quadruple digit connections on the second.

I'm curious about SQL security and performance, and while reading stuff up, this issue isn't one I've found a solution to : If I want to be secure and fast, is it better to keep users logged in on the server, and have the server access your SQL database, or is it better to give every user an SQL connection (I assume make this connection from the server to prevent people from stealing your login info via snooping in the game)?

Basically, should I make scripts on the server that access the database and keep concurrent connections to a minimum by only letting the server write to my SQL database (this is what I assume I should do for my game, as it will have some persistent online stats), or should I do a direct connection from the client to the database (which is how I see most tutorials do it, and which I assume would be more acceptable for the business side)?

Reading up on it but this hasn't been covered. I'd be leaning towards the first myself, as handling every connection request through the server and returning info via the server sounds more secure, but most applications I've seen do the second, and none of what I'm reading talks about either/or. PS: Yes I know there's a lot more I'll need to look up and that I will do for security and performance, I'm just curious on this question at the moment. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you end up doing is configuring a connection pool, this is the maximum number of concurrent connections you want to hand out to users, it also allows connections to be "reused" to a point.  Now in terms of the client connecting directly to the database, don't ever do that.  What you want to do is configure a non-privileged user account that only has read access to your database, this will be the account that retrieves data and passes it off to the client.  The critical piece is that this read-only account cannot write to the database, so it minimizes chances of data corruption.

Now what you need to do is have your application connect to a service or some type of interface that will filter out inappropriate data, such as attacks (SQL injection), once this data has been sanitized you can then pass it to your data layer.  Once inside the data layer you will open a connection and push the clean + safe data into your database.  The reader account will be able to retrieve it after the transaction has been committed.

So to recap you need at least two (2) database accounts.  One that is read-only, this is for the users and one that is for doing the work this is hidden in your application and cannot be externally accessed.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll flag this as an answer later today to leave me some room if I need a more info later and will look up more info based on this ^.^ Hopefully it will give me more to read and learn. - I was also aware of SQL and PHP injections and planning on filtering all incoming data, but did not think of making a read only database as I was planning on (originally) putting all database work on the server in C# scripts instead. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Charles it isn't so much a read-only database, it is a **user** that has read-only access.

Comment: That was originally how I was going to do it (and how it works now on my custom program). I misread database and database account and figured SQL would need a read only database, thanks for telling me to re read. >.>;;;

Comment: @Charles let me know if you have other questions/concerns

Answer (score -1):

The server is the one that handle the SQL queries.
Clients shouldn't have access to the SQL database.

Comment: not much information in this one, and it definitely doesn't answer the security aspect.